# Observer for Attribute Save After, Delete

Tags: event-observer

I know Observer for Attribute Set Save After is eav_entity_attribute_set_save_after . But I couldn't figure out if there is an observer for save attribute after and delete attribute after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eav_entity_attribute_save_after` or `eav_entity_attribute_delete_after`.
It works with `before`  also instead of `after`.

Comment: Isn't it `catalog_entity_attribute_save_*`?

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly, for catalog attributes yes it is, but for attributes in general it's [`eav_....`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute.php#L42)